# Why database isn't showed in Stetho

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, stetho

I have a database in my app. Here's the way how I create it:

`App` class:

```
public class TraktTvApp extends Application {

    private static Context sAppContext;
    public static TraktTvApp instance;
    private MovieDatabase database;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sAppContext = getApplicationContext();
        instance = this;
        database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, MovieDatabase.class, "MovieDatabase").build();
    }

    @NonNull
    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return sAppContext;
    }

    public static TraktTvApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public MovieDatabase getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

}
```

`DAO` class

```
@Dao
public interface MovieDao {

    @Query("SELECT * from MovieEntity")
    List<MovieEntity> getFavorites();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    Completable insertMovie(final MovieEntity movie);

    @Delete
    void deleteMovie(MovieEntity movie);

}
```

`Database` class

```
@Database(entities = {MovieEntity.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class MovieDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public abstract MovieDao movieDao();

}
```

And here's the way how I call `insert` method:

```
    mCompositeDisposable.add(Observable.fromCallable(()->movieDao.insertMovie(movieEntity))
            .doOnSubscribe(disposable -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(true))
            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                mView.showEmptyState(false);
                mView.onMoviesAdded();
            })
            .doOnError(throwable -> mView.showEmptyState(true))
            .doOnTerminate(() -> mView.showLoadingIndicator(false))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe());
```

But when I want to check data in my database in Stetho, there's nothing here:

[image]

So, what's the matter and how can I solve this problem? It seems to me that it can be problem in creating database, but I used the same way as usual and usually it works ok

Comment: Is your code for inserting - `movieDao.insertMovie(movieEntity)` - resulting in going into `doOnComplete(() -> {
                mView.showEmptyState(false);
                mView.onMoviesAdded();
            })` ?? Or you are getting error there only?

Comment: Add `Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this)` in application `onCreate()`

Comment: @AADProgramming, in onComplete.

Comment: @StanislavBondar, probably I had it in my start activity, but ok. When I moved that line to App nothing had changed

Answer (score 0):

call `setupDebugTools()` in application's `onCreate()` like

```
 {
   super.onCreate()
   setupDebugTools()
 }
```

And

```
  private void setupDebugTools() {

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this)

        }

    }
```

for more [information](https://github.com/facebook/stetho#putting-it-together)